# How do I set up trackingPixelUrl in craft / twig?

Tags: twig, craftcms

The tracking pixel is in the cms and the back end is functioning but I am unsure how to debug it on the front end.`

```
{% set trackingPixelUrl = entry['trackingPixelUrl'] is defined and 
entry.trackingPixelUrl is not empty ? entry.trackingPixelUrl  %}

{% if not craft.app.config.get('devMode') and trackingPixelUrl %}
<img src="{{ trackingPixelUrl }}" width="1" height="1">
{% endif %}'
```

This is how it is included in the default.html

```
 {% include 'products/_tracking-pixel' %}
```

I'm really new to twig and don't really understand how to debug this or what it's doing so if you can explain why this doesn't work that would be great. Thank you in advance

Comment: Just check the HTML source if the pixel is present?

Comment: It's not showing on the live site so something is broken somewhere
Would you be able to put me in the right direction, some ideas of why it's not showing?

Comment: It's seems to properly display the picture 1) The variable `entry` should be defined and contain the index `trackPixelUrl` 2) CraftsCMS can not be in development mode. (To verify `entry` u could do `{{ dump(entry) }}`

Comment: @DarkBee thank you for that - can you explain like I'm 5 please?

Comment: Which part? I'm not accustomed with craftcms myself. To enable/disable the devmode have a look [here](https://docs.craftcms.com/v2/config-settings.html) (this should also enable the dump function for twig it seems). As for the trackingPixelUrl I'm not sure - Is this a plugin you are using?